# Blank subreport in Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I'm trying to launch a report that I created in iReport which contains a main report and a subreport.  In iReport, the subreport launches fine and contains data, however when I try to launch it from within my java code, the subreport is blank.

What I've done so far:

- I have a String parameter in the main report called "SUBREPORT" that is used to define the path to the subreport.  E.g. value: "E:\java\ReportLauncher\reports\test_subreport1.jasper"
- The subreport expression in the main report is set to: $P{SUBREPORT}
- The subreport connection expression is: $P{REPORT_CONNECTION}
- I also have a subreport parameter defined called "INVOICE_NUMBER" that is set to $F{InviInvNo}, which maps to a field in the main report.

In my java code, I have:

```
HashMap<String, Object> paramHash = new HashMap();
paramHash.put("INVOICE_NUMBER", invoiceID);
paramHash.put("REPORT_CONNECTION", this.conn);
paramHash.put("SUBREPORT", subReportPath);

JasperPrint jasperprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(this.reportPath, paramHash, this.conn);
```

The main report is created fine and is populated.  The subreport area however is blank.  Any thoughts for what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Andy.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't mention anything about the subreport query:

If you are using the Detail Band in the subreport, then you will need a Data Query for the report.

In old iReport, from `Data` menu, choose `Report Query` and write your query here. If you want only one record (i.e. Detail band only one time) you can use a dummy table. Like:

```
SELECT 'a' FROM DUMMY
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to use the Detail Band, you have the option to view the other bands without using a query. From `Edit` menu, choose `Report Properties`, under `More...` tab, set the flag `When no data` to `All Sections, no detail`