# Results from 2 mdx queries on same jaspersoft report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, mdx, olap, cube

I have 2 mdx queries. Each of them return 1 record with 1 column.
 I am interested in showing single tuple value from each mdx query result side by side on same report (using jaspersoft ireport).

Note: The 2 mdx queries are fetching data from different cubes and there is no connection between the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make two subreports with your two queries and then add them both to a master report with a 'dummy' query. Then you could have them side-by-side on the same report.

Here's a link similar to what I'm talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2574475/1211525